# What is a 'Swivel Servant'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

English is not my first language.  I googled and googled, but this was one thing I was not able to find.  Can someone give me a definition of this?

Comment: Interresting. My searches shows that the expression clearly has been used, but there is no explanation for it. Perhaps it's a misheard expression.

Comment: More info. and context:  I saw it on a website where a guy was describing himself as employed by the government as a 'swivel servant'.  I wonder if it was just a case of miss-spelling 'civil servant'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably a play on words - *swivel* and *civil* sound similar in pronunciation. It can either be a form of mockery or wordplay (for example, in [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWb6F49oZTo)) almost as if it's taboo to say 'civil servant', or it could simply be a misheard expression, as Guffa said.

Comment: Nice find for the song! Note that at 1:10 he sings "If wrk should appear, swivel your chair and plug your ears", so for him at least a "swivel servant" is a government employee (civil servant) who spends all their time spinning on a [swivel chair](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Desk_chair.jpg/225px-Desk_chair.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

I had not heard this term before today, but my first thought was of a [lazy-susan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_Susan) style device.  After some searching, it seems [I could be right](http://www.samsclub.com/sams/shop/product.jsp?productId=200413), however the word *swivel* has been adopted as the [name of a company](http://www.swivelsecure.com) which sells servers (not servants) hence *swivel server*. Swivel Servant might be a simple (incorrect) variation of Swivel server.